# refresh html page content every minute using jboss Seam

Tags: java, jboss, page-refresh, jboss-seam

I'm developing a system using the Jboss Seam environment. I have reached a part where i need to create a page that automatically refreshes it's content every minute or so. 
The page is supposed to be displayed in a tv in our workroom and displays some data from a database that is populated by the other staff in our company, and we need to be updated about these new additions in real time.

I am new to developing in Jboss Seam and my supervisor doesn't know how to do this as well, so i'm resorting to S.O

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Jboss developer is not the technology your app is built on, it is your ide. You need to share the framework you are using.

Comment: any idea on how I can see the name of the framework?

Comment: Jboss Seam is the framework i believe

Answer (score 0):

A very easy "hack" is to add this tag to your html page:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
</head>
```

Your browser will reload the page every minute

Comment: thanks, i checked it using the debugger in chrome and it worked. do you know how i can add this meta tag to the head tag in my page?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure about how to do it in JBoss Seam.